# How to handle salesforce Username-Password Oauth Authentication Flow token expiry?

Tags: python, authentication, oauth, salesforce

```
import requests

consumer_key = "mykeyshere"
consumer_secret = "secret here"
username = "usernamehere"
password = "pass here"
payload = {
'grant_type': 'password',
'client_id': consumer_key,
'client_secret': consumer_secret,
'username': username,
'password': password
}

def getToken():
    res = requests.post("https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token",headers={"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},data=payload)
    if res.status_code==200:
        #get the token from the response 
        #AND make the API call you want
```

Here I have implemented SalesForce **Username-Password Oauth Authentication Flow** for authorization and to receive the token.

The Code is working Great and I have  set the token expiry to be 1 months for now.

What happens after the token gets expired as this is a Username-Password Oauth Authentication We wont have a **refresh token**. How can I handle it. Do I have to regenerate all those keys passed as payload again after it expires. What is the best way to handle such situation.

Please don't recommend me to use the OAUTH2 verification instead.As I am working from console based application, I found this a right choice.

*If it was a oauth2 I could have also make the reauthorize again at least.*

Proposed solution:
I don't know if it is the right solutions.We can set the expiry time of the token from Salesforce developer. If I unset that than it will show something like this in the picture.

[image]
What does it mean ?Does it mean its valid its valid for unlimited time ?